# Выбор из БД записей с временем меньшим текущего

Tags: база-данных, sql

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся новости. Но новости могут быть запланированными, т.е. с датой и временем большим текущего. Нужно выбрать единственную новость, подходящую по времени. Так сказать, последнюю видимую.

Пишу такой код:

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE date<=NOW() ORDER BY date DESC
```

Но он выбирает новость за предыдущий день. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Новость за предыдущий день отвечает условию. Вот если бы была за будущие, тогда стоило бы волноваться. А так я бы в данные заглянул. Может там и нет тех дат, которые вы ожидаете. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datetime не зависит от часового пояса, а тип данных timestamp учитывает часовой пояс, возможно в этом проблема? попробовать например cast(now() as datetime)

Answer (score 0):

А у колонки date у вас какой тип данных?
Ошибка может быть, например, в настройках временной зоны сервера.
Кстати, ещё можно LIMIT 1 в конце написать ;-)

Comment: у колонки date тип datetime. Limit не написал, потому что беру потом только одну строку. 
Интересует такой вопрос - NOW() берет время из настроек SQL или из, кхм, php? (в php-скрипте стоит "date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-4');")